# Terminal prompt disappears when a named pipe is used

Tags: named-pipes, prompt, csh, mkfifo

I'm trying to use named pipes in a project. I have two terminals open, Terminal A and Terminal B.

In terminal A, I issued this command:

`mkfifo myFifo && tail -f myFifo | csh -s`

It seems as if standard out is being redirected somewhere else, though, because my prompt disappears and some commands aren't reflected in terminal A.

For example, if in terminal B I begin a python session via issuing `echo "python" > myFifo`, then `echo "print 'Hello, World'" > myFifo`, I don't see Hello, World in terminal A.

However, if I issue `echo ls > myFifo` within terminal B, I see the correct output from `ls` in terminal A.

Does anyone know why sometimes the output appears and sometime it doesn't?

I'm running on CentOS 6.6

Thanks,
erip

Answer (score 0):

You read from the FIFO with `csh`, if you start an interactive Python shell in `csh`, then it won't be reading from the FIFO because it's busy running `python`.

Python doesn't somehow automagically do a REPL on the FIFO. How should it even *know* about the FIFO? It has no knowledge of it.

You could, perhaps, tell Python to read commands from the FIFO with something like:

```
>>> import os, sys, time
>>> fifo = open(os.open('myFifo',  os.O_NONBLOCK), 'r')
```

And then:

```
$ echo 'print(42+5)' > ! myFifo
```

Will give you:

```
>>> eval(fifo.read())
47
```

Perhaps there's also a way to tell Python to read commands from `myFifo` by overwriting `sys.stdin`, but I can't get that working in my testing.

It's a bit unclear to me what exactly you're trying to achieve here, though. I suspect there might be another solution which is much more appropriate to the problem you're having.